# Searching an array for a value in booking system

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a hotel booking system to be displayed through the console. The system should allow the user to select up to 10 room numbers (1-10) and give the customers name that is being booked in. Below I have put a method to keep all the rooms empty when the program is run.

```
private static void initialise(String hotelRef[]) {
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    hotelRef[x] = "EMPTY";
    }
}
```

Below I am trying to look through the hotel system array to see if a customer is found. At the moment, n elements are picked up. Can anyone tell me how to search for an element?

```
  System.out.println("Please enter the customer name:");
            String findCust = input.next();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                if (findCust.equals(hotel[x])) {
                    System.out.println("Room " + x + " is occupied by " + hotel[x]);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Customer is not found.");
                    exitToMenu(hotel);

                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to restructure your code a bit. Just stop the loop if there is a match. Then after the loop, use a boolean to say if a room is occupied or if a customer isn't found before returning to the menu. Although I suggest to introduce a method to search a room by name. Then the code is re-usable. But I guess you're new in programming so that's not for now

Answer (score 0):

Your loop stops after the first iteration. You need to change your code to something like:

```
int y = -1;
 for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
 {
  if (findCust.equals(hotel[x]))
  {
            y = x;
            break;

  }
}
  if(y!=-1)
  {
  System.out.println("Room " + x + " is occupied by " + hotel[x]);

  } else 
 {
  System.out.println("Customer is not found.");
  exitToMenu(hotel);

 }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working so far. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Do hotel and hotelRef refer the same array ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to a list using `Arrays.asList()`and use the method `<arraylistName>.contains(Object)` to check if the object is present.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (findCust.equals(hotel[x])) {
     System.out.println("Room " + x + " is occupied by " + hotel[x]);

} else {
     System.out.println("Customer is not found.");
     exitToMenu(hotel);

}
```

In the above code, hotelRef array and hotel array is same ? If it is not try to use hotelRef[ ] instead of hotel[ ].

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working so far. But thanks anyway.